# Save binary file that has been auto-generated in classic asp

Tags: asp-classic, filesystemobject

I have a perl script that generates a midi file in the browser. I would like to run a classic asp script that binary reads the outputted midi file and saves it to the server. The file is however generated using a querystring, which it is not possible to read into the FileSystemObject using GetFile

What I would like is something like

```
Set objFSO = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile("1090.pl?chord=C&chord_id=1090")
```

This however doesn't work. I'm looking for ideas or other ways how to read this auto-generated midi file into a binary object which I can then save to the server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the file system object for this purpose, instead you can use the XMLHTTP object. Here's an example of how to use it. Note you will need to change strFileURL (the URL for your 1090.pl script) and strHDLocation (where to save on the server - you will also need to ensure the website has read/write permissions to whatever location you choose).

```
<% 
' Set your settings 
strFileURL = "http://localhost/1090.pl?chord=C&chord_id=1090" 
strHDLocation = "c:\filename.ext"

' Fetch the file 
Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

objXMLHTTP.open "GET", strFileURL, false 
objXMLHTTP.send()

If objXMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then 
    Set objADOStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream") 
    objADOStream.Open 
    objADOStream.Type = 1 'adTypeBinary

    objADOStream.Write objXMLHTTP.ResponseBody 
    objADOStream.Position = 0 'Set the stream position to the start

    Set objFSO = Createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
    If objFSO.Fileexists(strHDLocation) Then objFSO.DeleteFile strHDLocation 
    Set objFSO = Nothing

    objADOStream.saveToFile strHDLocation 
    objADOStream.Close 
    Set objADOStream = Nothing 
End if

Set objXMLHTTP = Nothing 
%>
```